# How to extract only the odd position value of an string?

Tags: string, c#-3.0

I have a string Data="0 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0";
I want to extract only the odd position of Data.
I mean New string with value:-0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Please add some code to display what you have tried so far

Comment: What is it that makes a character 'odd'? When you say 'extract', do you really mean 'remove'? When you include so little information in your question, it leaves people to guess what you really mean, and makes it much more likely you will get answers that don't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var Data="0 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0";
var output= string.Join(" ", Data
                               .Split(' ')
                               .Select ((s,i) =>new {s,i})
                               .Where (w =>w.i % 2 != 0 )
                               .Select (s => s.s));
```

Output will be:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

You could also do this:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetOdd(string data)
{
    var split=data.Split(' ');
    for(int i=0;i<split.Length;i++)
    {
        if(i % 2 != 0)
            yield return split[i];
    }
}
```

And then call the function like this:

```
var output= string.Join(" ", GetOdd(Data))
```